# errorbar, but not line, as marker symbol in python matplotlib legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I have a errorbar plot with only one data point (i.e. one errorbar) per data set. Therefore I would like to have a single errorbar symbol in the legend as well.
The single one can be achieved by `legend(numpoints=1)`. Using this in the following code:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    ax.errorbar(x=[0.3], y=[0.7], xerr=[0.2], marker='+', markersize=10, label='horizontal marker line')
    ax.errorbar(x=[0.7], y=[0.3], yerr=[0.2], marker='+', markersize=10, label='is too long')

    ax.set_xlim([0,1])
    ax.set_ylim([0,1])
    ax.legend(numpoints=1) # I want only one symbol

    plt.show()
```

results in these symbols in the legend:
[image: errorbars in legend are mixed up with lines]

As you see, the errorbars are mixed up with horizontal lines, that make sense when there are more than one error bars to be connected (using  `legend(numpoints=2)` or higher), but look ugly in my case.

How can I get rid of the lines in the legend markers without loosing the errorbars?

Comment: Did the answer below solve your problem? If so accept it, otherwise comment what further problems you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the default settings in matplotlib. At the start of your code you can change them by changing the settings using `rcParams`:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mpl.rcParams['legend.handlelength'] = 0
mpl.rcParams['legend.markerscale'] = 0

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.errorbar(x=[0.3], y=[0.7], xerr=[0.2], marker='+', markersize=10, label='horizontal marker')
ax.errorbar(x=[0.7], y=[0.3], yerr=[0.2], marker='+', markersize=10, label='is gone')

ax.set_xlim([0,1])
ax.set_ylim([0,1])
ax.legend(numpoints=1) 
plt.show()
```

Note: This changes the settings for all the graphs that will be plotted in the code.